# Create a new "dotnet new angular --name test" with a specific Angular version

Tags: .net, angular

How do you create a new "dotnet new angular --name test" With a specific version of Angular. I can't find any docs that show you how to do this.

Comment: What you're looking for is not possible. The VS template comes with Angular 8, that is it.

Comment: Dang. I wonder if they will ever update it to a newer version.

Comment: I would like to think they would. Angular changes quickly, I imagine they find it difficult to keep up with it. They are 4 major versions behind! For now, I just end up creating a new application using the CLI and overwriting what comes with the VS template.

Comment: i would let dotnet out of it... just use angular.

Comment: I will have to do the same thing. It would be nice to have the option in the future Microsoft! haha.